# Android: SMS and MMS Project

Tags: android, sms, android-service, mms, android-broadcast

I'm newbie in Android development and I have some questions to afford a new project.

The app must send and receive SMS and MMS to store then in a remote database through a WebService.

I need structure the project but I'm not sure what kind of components (activities, services, content providers or broadcast receivers) I will need to develop this functions.

For example: I know the existence of Intent-filters but I'm not sure if it will running if the application is closed and it's better a service to check for new sms/mms.

¿How would you design that?

Thanks!

Comment: where do you want to store the data.......

Comment: I think you just have to start somewhere and gradually improve your implementation. This is the most stable way to intercept SMS that I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095422/communication-between-two-device-using-sms/20096259#20096259

Comment: @Barun in a remote database

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have done with the xml file.Now in Activity class use http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/ to send sms using smsmanager API.

Also for using remote database you need an api to call that database and there you have to use  asyncTask to send that data methods

Comment: I use ksoap2 to call the webservice, that's not a problem. What I'm not sure is if a Service class is needed with a BroadcastReceiver.

Send SMS is so easy with SMSmanager but send a MMS is very complex. I know you can call an Intent to send it from the Message Application but it's not the idea.

Comment: use BroadcastReceiver to send data.No need to call Service class with BroadcastReceiver.Both are different things.

Comment: Service class runs in background always and hamper battery performance